# Google tag manager events not appearing in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

A client has requested that we implement google tag manager on to track submission of all the forms on his website. We have set up all of the tags and triggers per the instructions that we found online but it appears that only 1 tag is actually working. We the Solids Conveying Case Studies event appear in the behavior > events> overview screen of analytics but not in the Real Time screen. All other tags do not appear to fire at all. We did view the preview/debug mode and see what appears to be a glimpse of a tag after the form submits and the page reloads. Also during our debugging process we tried setting the action to trigger on the form id, and we tried checking Wait for Tags. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to the website: https://foxvalve.com

Here is an example of a tag that we set up.

**Tag Type:** Universal Analytics

**Track Type:** Event

**Category:** Air Gas Ejectors (Different Depending on the Form)

**Action:** Submit

**Label:** Form

**Value:** empty

**Non-Interaction Hit:** True

**Google Analytics Settings:** Google Analytics Variable

**Trigger Configuration**

**Trigger Type:** Form Submission

**Trigger Fires On** Page URL equals (the page URL of the form)

Comment: Get the Google Analytics Debugger extension for chrome and repeat the process with the checkbox preserved log in the console on. If you cant see the event there the problem is the trigger. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

Comment: Check if the URL has tag manager correctly implemented, for example https://www.foxvalve.com/forms.cfm doesnt have tag manager. Only has the old ga script. Finally, if u can give the url of the form and i ll test it.

Comment: We were actually able to solve the problem, and you found the first part of it. Forms.cfm was not pulling in the manager as it was supposed to, and we had the event fire on the url which included www. but when our forms submitted it removed the www. from the url causing the tag not to fire.